# How can I convolution image in CUDA

Tags: cuda, convolution

I have a question about image convolution in CUDA. When I test it with small maxtrix (16*16) evething is ok. But with larger matrix, the result is always change when I run. 
I think problem is 2 for loops into kernel.

```
__global__ void image_convolution_kernel(float *input, float *out, float *kernelConv,
                    int img_width, const int img_height,
                    const int kernel_width, const int kernel_height )
{

    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    float sum = 0;
    for ( int j = 0; j < kernel_height; j++ )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < kernel_width; i++ )
        {
            int dX = x + i - kernel_width / 2;
            int dY = y + j - kernel_height / 2;

            if ( dX < 0 )
                dX = 0;

            if ( dX >= img_width )
                dX = img_width - 1;

            if ( dY < 0 )
                dY = 0;

            if ( dY >= img_height )
                dY = img_height - 1;


            const int idMat = j * kernel_width + i;
            const int idPixel = dY * img_width + dX;
            sum += (float)input[idPixel] * kernelConv[idMat];
        }
    }

    const int idOut = y * img_width + x;
    out[idOut] = abs(sum);

}

  void image_convolution(float * input,float* output, int img_height, int img_width)
{
    int kernel_height = 3;
    int kernel_width = 3;
    float kernel[] ={ 0,-0.25,0,
                     -0.25,1,-0.25,
                      0,-0.25,0
                    };
    float * mask = new float[kernel_height*kernel_width];
    for (int i = 0; i < kernel_height*kernel_width; i++)
    {
        mask[i] = kernel[i];
    }

    float * d_input, * d_output, * d_kernel;
    cudaMalloc(&d_input, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_output, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_kernel, kernel_height*kernel_width*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(d_input, input, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_kernel, mask, kernel_height*kernel_width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 blocksize(16,16);
    dim3 gridsize;
    gridsize.x=(img_width+blocksize.x-1)/blocksize.x;
    gridsize.y=(img_height+blocksize.y-1)/blocksize.y;
    image_convolution_kernel<<<gridsize,blocksize>>>(d_input,d_output,d_kernel,img_width,img_height,kernel_width,kernel_height);
    cudaMemcpy(output, d_output, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i < img_width*img_height; i++)
    {
         printf("%d, ",(int)output[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Here is my result, I test it with 24*24 image, I run it 2 time, and I also write simple function to compared the output.

[image]

And here is result when I compare the output, there are 32 differents,at index 240, 241 ....
[image]

Comment: @RobertCrovella sorry, I was updated the code and output with pictures, please give me some advises.

Comment: When you want to include text-based data in a question, its suggested that you copy and paste the actual text (and format it!) instead of pasting pictures of the text into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a fairly common error in your program.  When you create a grid of threads like this:

```
dim3 blocksize(16,16);
dim3 gridsize;
gridsize.x=(img_width+blocksize.x-1)/blocksize.x;
gridsize.y=(img_height+blocksize.y-1)/blocksize.y;
```

you are intentionally creating (usually) *extra* threads in each dimension, so as to fully cover the problem space (i.e. image size).  There is nothing wrong with this.

However, it means we will be launching **extra** threads, which are outside the valid image dimension.  We must ensure that these threads do *nothing*.  The usual approach is to add a thread check to the kernel, so that threads outside the valid image dimensions do nothing.  Here's a modified kernel and fully worked example showing that change:

```
$ cat t1219.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int iw = 1025;
const int ih = 1025;
const int rng = 10;

__global__ void image_convolution_kernel(float *input, float *out, float *kernelConv,
                    int img_width, const int img_height,
                    const int kernel_width, const int kernel_height )
{

    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if ((x < img_width) && (y < img_height)){  // thread check
      float sum = 0;
      for ( int j = 0; j < kernel_height; j++ )
      {
        for ( int i = 0; i < kernel_width; i++ )
        {
            int dX = x + i - kernel_width / 2;
            int dY = y + j - kernel_height / 2;

            if ( dX < 0 )
                dX = 0;

            if ( dX >= img_width )
                dX = img_width - 1;

            if ( dY < 0 )
                dY = 0;

            if ( dY >= img_height )
                dY = img_height - 1;


            const int idMat = j * kernel_width + i;
            const int idPixel = dY * img_width + dX;
            sum += (float)input[idPixel] * kernelConv[idMat];
        }
      }

      const int idOut = y * img_width + x;
      out[idOut] = abs(sum);
    }

}

  void image_convolution(float * input,float* output, int img_height, int img_width)
{
    int kernel_height = 3;
    int kernel_width = 3;
    float kernel[] ={ 0,-0.25,0,
                     -0.25,1,-0.25,
                      0,-0.25,0
                    };
    float * mask = new float[kernel_height*kernel_width];
    for (int i = 0; i < kernel_height*kernel_width; i++)
    {
        mask[i] = kernel[i];
    }

    float * d_input, * d_output, * d_kernel;
    cudaMalloc(&d_input, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_output, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_kernel, kernel_height*kernel_width*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(d_input, input, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_kernel, mask, kernel_height*kernel_width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 blocksize(16,16);
    dim3 gridsize;
    gridsize.x=(img_width+blocksize.x-1)/blocksize.x;
    gridsize.y=(img_height+blocksize.y-1)/blocksize.y;
    image_convolution_kernel<<<gridsize,blocksize>>>(d_input,d_output,d_kernel,img_width,img_height,kernel_width,kernel_height);
    cudaMemcpy(output, d_output, img_width*img_height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

int main(){

  float *in, *out;
  int is = ih*iw;
  in  = new float[is];
  out = new float[is];
  for (int i = 0; i < is; i++) {in[i] = rand()%rng; out[i] = -1;}
  image_convolution(in,out, ih, iw);
  for (int iy = 1; iy < ih-1; iy++)
    for (int ix = 1; ix < iw-1; ix++){
      float temp = abs(-0.25 * (in[iy*iw + ix -1] + in[iy*iw + ix +1] + in[(iy-1)*iw + ix] + in[(iy+1)*iw + ix]) + in[iy*iw+ix]);
      if (out[iy*iw+ix] != temp) {std::cout << "mismatch x: " << ix << " y: " << iy << " was: " << out[iy*iw+ix] << " should be: " << temp << std::endl; return 1;}}
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1219 t1219.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1219
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

For image dimensions which are exact multiples of the block size (16,16) (which was true for my previous test case) this problem won't show up -- the code will work correctly.  For all other test cases, we need such a thread check.